# How can I use the value of a variable in an IN statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

example:

```
SET @numbers:= '1,2,3,4,5,6';

SELECT * FROM table WHERE t.number in (@numbers);

UPDATE table SET name = 'test' WHERE t.number in (@numbers);
```

How can I use the value of a variable in an IN statement? As in the request above

Comment: `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(t.number, @numbers)`. Or use dynamic Sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `IN` on a CSV string like that.

But you can use it with `FIND_IN_SET`

```
SET @numbers:= '1,2,3,4,5,6';

UPDATE your_table t
SET name = 'test' 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(t.number, @numbers) != 0;

SELECT * 
FROM your_table t
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(t.number, @numbers) != 0;
```

In MySql 8 you could also unfold such CSV string as a `JSON_TABLE`.
And use that as a query for the `IN`.

```
SET @numbers:= '1,2,3,4,5,6';

UPDATE your_table t
SET name = 'test'
WHERE t.number IN (SELECT num FROM JSON_TABLE(CONCAT('[',@numbers,']'),'$[*]' COLUMNS(num INT PATH '$'))nums); 

SELECT *
FROM your_table t
WHERE t.number IN (SELECT num FROM JSON_TABLE(CONCAT('[',@numbers,']'),'$[*]' COLUMNS(num INT PATH '$'))nums);
```